# How to update div on database update

Tags: php, database, html, chat

I have made a code for chatting and it is member based this is the code:

The code is available here : [Code For Chat.php](http://pastebin.com/PKUZJ8LH)

What I want is it to update the `div` id window everytime there is a update/insert/change in the database as if I have it update every X number of seconds A) it is too fast or B) too slow...

Comment: FYI `session_start();` needs to be at the top of your file. It will send a HTTP header which can only be sent before you output any content to the browser.

Comment: Yes I have a session_start(); in all my pages as it is member based.

Comment: No, it must be at the TOP of the file. You have it on line 53, please read my above comment carefully.

Answer (score 0):

A solution could be: Save the hour/minutes when you make your last update in DB in a txt file(or something like this) and compare it with the time when your jquery is accessed. If these two "times" are different get your data from DB.(I think this is the fastest way)